# nexus 7 3g won't flash Ubuntu touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I am unsuccessfully trying to flash any Ubuntu touch daily onto my N7 tilapia. I followed the instructions from Ubuntu wiki for tilapia step by step. The fastboot method ended up with terminal saying "waiting for device" while the N7 booted into fastboot mode by itself. I waited for several hours, nothing happened. Manual install method in recovery aborted because the zip is for grouper and won't install on tilapia.

Can someone please help me? As a long-term Ubuntu user on PC and laptop I am eagerly waiting for Ubuntu touch on a tablet. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

First identify that you are indeed in fastboot, you can do this looking at the screen and noticing:

- A Start label with something resembling an arrow pointing to the power button.
- An open android.
- Text with device information.

With the cable plugged in, run:

```
fastboot devices
```

If it doesn't return anything while in fastboot mode it's most likely a permission problem, by running

```
sudo fastboot devices
```

you can prove that it is. To get this working and continue your workflow either use sudo or make sure the proper udev rules are in, to create on, look at dmesg while in fastboot mode and identify a line similar to:

```
New USB device found, idVendor=18d1, idProduct=4ee0
```

If you have adb-android-fastboot installed you can look at:

```
/lib/udev/rules.d/70-android-tools-fastboot.rules
```

to replicate them in /etc/udev/rules.d/ or propose a fix with a patch to android-tools, the easiest way to do this is through a bug in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/android-tools/+filebug

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is that your driver is installed incorrectly. As a result, your computer cannot see your devices response. To fix this, try installing [PdaNet](http://foxfi.com/).
During the installation, keep your device unplugged until told to plug it in, and be sure that USB Debugging is enabled under Developer Options. If you don't see Developer Options in your settings menu, go to About Tablet, then tap Build Number seven times. This will enable Developer Options. After installing PdaNet, you should be able to install Ubuntu Touch without issue.